# What should a developer prioritise to improve employment prospects?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

My situation is:

- In full time employment as software developer using up-to-date
  "popular" front and back end technologies. Enjoy my job and work to
  improve my skills / stay relevant.
- No formal qualifications or certifications.
- Approx. 15 years work experience as a developer from Junior to
  Senior.
- Concerned that I may not be competitive if I need to find a similar
  new role, especially for high interest remote working jobs.

Looking at ten or so job postings on Stack Overflow, only one had a  qualification (computer science or related degree) as a requirement. All asked for skills / experience in ***list of technologies***.

To get to the stage where a candidate is able to prove their skills, what should be considered most valuable to work on from hirers' point of view:

- Publishing / maintaining a public repository of personal coding
  projects.
- Contributing to open source projects.
- Building Stack
  Overflow profile / reputation by being a useful contributor.
- Gaining professional certifications / working towards other qualifications.
- Anything I've missed.

Obviously all this and more might be, but given usual work / life time constraints, what to prioritise?

Comment: Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision.

Comment: Appreciate it is objective but I feel this is relevant to software development career progression in general and the list I made covers common software dev activities so answers could be helpful to others interested in these tags.

Comment: You have missed an important one, professional network. With that much experience you should know a few people.

Comment: Good point, it's important. I deliberately missed it off because I wanted this to be about showcasing what you know in the case of applying for jobs.

Comment: @John And as expected and by the answers, there is no real way to answer, just to state opinions. hence why i VTC.

Comment: What you really need is a poll/survey of employers about what they want from job seekers. Wouldn't help you in the near term but I would support that feature request.

Comment: @BSMP yep it had crossed my mind before that an employer survey would be useful. Thanks all for the comments / answers.

Answer (score 1):

With 15 years' experience, don't just know *how* to program. You have a strategic view that encompasses the entire lifecycle of the stuff you're working on.

- Why do people want it?
- How do we know that's what they want?
- How do we deliver what they want effectively? securely?
- How do we know when it's done?
- When will we next have to re-do it because of changing technology or other factors?

As you put your resume together, think through the work you've done, answer these questions to yourself.

For interviews, prepare by coming up with some specific examples where your team turned out to understand these things well. How did YOU help them get that understanding?

And, come up with a case or two where strategic misunderstanding caused some kind of trouble (missed sales, cost overrun, somebody got mad and quit, etc.)

Be ready to answer this question "If you could do that project over, what would you do differently."

That kind of meta-view of projects is just as important than whether you know a particular language or other bunch of tech stuff.

You do know this strategic stuff about your projects. Leverage your knowledge.

Comment: Great answer also thanks. Gets outside of the thinking about coding mentality.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what to prioritise depends strongly on the culture of the company you want to apply to. If you don't know that yet, you'll have a hard time prioritising.

Lets think about it the other way. What are your strong points? You should focus on those, because that will help you in interviews with companies that value the stuff you're good at!

Do you eat exams for breakfast? Go for certifications, find out which ones are the hard ones that require significant technical skill / understanding and get those. If you're lucky you might even get your current employer into it and (partly) do them on paid time. Depending on the company, these might even be hard requirements because of legal obligations / client requirements.

Do you enjoy developing something in your free time? Then go with either option one or two. Which one is basically up to taste, if you're going with open source just make sure an interested future employer can easily spot your contributions.

The worth of an StackOverflow-Profile is pretty volatile: Some companies will see a lot of value in a person who shows both understanding and willingness to help others, while some companies will not care at all. SO is just too young to be an established factor in the evaluation of a potential future employee, so i won't rely on just that.

What you might have forgotten: Does your current company have a public facing product you contributed to?

Comment: Thanks, the majority of job postings I've seen over last few years follow the format outlined in question and many of the companies give the impression of having a similar culture in their postings. That of a "modern" software development company. So I feel a certain approach could be productive with a majority of the postings.

Comment: There is no such things as a unified culture to modern software development companies. What they look for in employees differs vastly by past experiences, legal and client requirements, what the responsible HR busybody feels like and stuff like such. In such companies I've seen anything from "the CEO hires whoever his gut tells him to" to companies that had complex internal metrics to evaluate everyones CV against before an interview was even considered. sadly, there is no catch-all here.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. My gut feeling is that there is a one size fits many, but in reality, your answer highlights the old fact that being strong in as many areas as possible gives the best opportunities. Also, good point re public facing product.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 15 years of development experience, I'm not terribly interested in any of those. I will assume that all of those bullet points are dwarfed by your actual experience on the job. Any of it is cool and probably a little bonus, but none of it is going to make it or break it.

What I would be interested in is any kind of certification for abilities or skills that are *not* obvious on first glance. For example, if you developed backends in C# and you show me a certificate for ASP.NET, then that's kinda redundant. I will assume you know or can learn some form of ASP.NET from the fact that you did backends in C# for a living. Now, show me a certificate for Scrum training. Or show me a certificate that shows you are licensed to train apprentices. Show me something I don't know about you, show me something *on top* of what your 15 years tell. That's a big bonus.

Comment: Ok, makes sense cheers. The skills / experience should speak for themselves so earn then highlight additional values.

Answer (score 0):

**Certifications** are one of the best ways to showcase your skill, knowledge and set yourself apart from other developers. Its essentially you putting your money where your mouth is, and for many good certifications, you will need to pay.

Now a lot of certifications might seem useless, but you have to remember something. A certification is essentially a 3rd party guaranteeing you have the skills to use a certain platform or code in a certain language. An Amazon certifications is going to be great if your applying for a company heavily focused in AWS. A Microsoft or Azure certificate is great for an Azure environment. Cisco certification for hardware, Sales force certification for being a Sales force developer.

These big certifications work better than a open source project or your own code projects. Its a big name company telling the rest of the world. This guy here. We guarantee that he can work with this platform. You just need to make sure that whoever is granting you the certification has a good name in your industry and that it isn't stupidly easy to obtain (there are so many worthless free certifications you can obtain online...).

Otherwise, you want to make sure you have the **experience**, **knowledge** and **foresight** to work in large projects. This is hard to sell. You need good examples of problems you've overcome. Projects you have completed and in general, the ability to see things at a high level and identify issues from very early on.

For example, you could say: I was working on project X and was given a brief overview. I was able to identify that we would face technological issues around stage Y. I was able to request technology Z a month in advance and when we reached stage Y we were able to apply technology Z straight away.

Any developer can be given a project. Dive right in and solve all their issues with google search. But having the ability to foresee future problems and plan your solutions out accordingly can be very rare.

Comment: Thanks another good answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Approx. 15 years work experience as a developer from Junior to Senior.

With this you already will land most jobs - or rather get to the interview stage. Or not. Anything else you mentioned will not make much of a difference. Still, below is a ranking of what makes more or less sense. Still, I'd rather suggest to do what is interesting and fun for you than to go by the list. The more motivated you are to do it the more likely you actually pull through with it. And in principle, you don't need to do anything to have a shot. The actual challenge will be the interviews, but that's not what you asked for. So here a list on what helps on a CV:

## 1) Contribution to open source projects

- the more popular and well known the better, it's actually a second job then and shows you can handle multiple projects; the "other side" may also use them and be thankful for your contribution, which would be a little emotional plus; it also means your code is reviewed and you need to be able to work with a separate team with potentially different rules than your primary work team

## 2 a) Publishing / maintaining a public repository of personal coding projects.

- especially helpful if you cannot share code from your work and want to save time in doing coding tests: The other side can quickly get some feel for your coding style and abilities. However, they still may want to test you within their controlled environment / test.

## 2 b) Building Stack Overflow profile / reputation by being a useful contributor.

- in general close to the personal repository, both can be of use regarding certain types of interviewers and their processes / what they are looking for
- especially helpful when you would have a teaching/leading role as it can show you are able to present technical solutions in a concise manor others understand

## 3) Certificates

- most certificates are kinda pointless at your level and for looking for similar jobs. Except for very specific jobs, I don't see how a certificate brings any benefit when you can claim 15 years work experience in the technologies you get a certificate for. Sometimes they can even be a hindrance: They can distract and give rise to thought processes like "why would someone do certificates when they could chase interesting projects?".
- they can be helpful to prove you know a technology you never actually worked with (but would convince me only of basic level knowledge in most cases)
- they are absolutely helpful in certain areas that require certain certificates to work as a certified X either by law of by contract (e.g. for bug supporters etc.), but in that case you would likely have them already

Comment: Thanks @Frank Hopkins, another very helpful response,. Your answer prompts me to admit that, although I was thinking about the points in my question anyway, the main trigger for the question is that in the last few months, I've applied for two (in my country) remote working jobs and heard nothing back. Which made me think, what else do I need to do? As I have a CV with a strong list of skills / experience.

Answer (score -1):

A *public* repository and contribution to Open Source projects is of very little value. I have a *non public* repository for a an actual product. I can give access to prospective employers, and it's made very clear that I'm the copyright holder and access is for having a look at it with no further rights. I work for money, not for charity. (Sometimes I do things for fun).

I also have a few code snippets that are not of much particular value on their own, but show that I have some deep knowledge in interesting parts of development.